# Symfony2 embedded form and left join entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I got two entities that works fine using a doctrine left join.
The problem occours when I try to edit using a form and Description is null (no row found). How do I make sure that Description.productid is populated with Product.productid ?

```
object(Test\AdminBundle\Entity\Product)#245 (5) {
  ["productid":protected]=>
  string(4) "8989"
  ["product":protected]=>
  string(12) "Test Test"
  ["price":protected]=>
  string(4) "9,95"
  ["groupid":protected]=>
  string(2) "72"
  ["description":protected]=>
 object(Test\AdminBundle\Entity\Description)#417 (3) {
    ["productid":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["description":protected]=>
    string(4) "qweq fdasd"
  }
}

class Product
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"edit"})
     * @Assert\Range(min = "100", max = "99999", groups={"search", "edit"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $productid;

    ...

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="Test\AdminBundle\Entity\Description")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Description", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productid", referencedColumnName="productid")
     */
    protected $description; 

    ...
}


class Description
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $productid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    ...
}
```

My tables (mysql myisam) are all using the same productid as primary key:

```
product
productid | price | morecolumns | ...

description
productid | description | morecolumns | ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `$description->setProduct($this)` in the `addDescription(Description $description)` method of the `Product` entity. So whenever you add new description object to a product it automatically populate the field.

Comment: I made it work by adding `$this->description->setProductid($this->getProductid());` to setDescription. Is this the prefered solution? I thought my entity class needed to be edited for doctrine to handle this.

Comment: Its better to set the whole object, not just its ID. So just call `$this->description->setProduct($this);` instead of `$this->description->setProductid($this->getProductid());` and doctrine will automatically recognize its ID. This is prefered solution.

Comment: I see, but my `Description` entity do not have a `setProduct` method as it's a unidirectional relation.